# How to run a command after a certain time while another command is running?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which will be running a main command, let's say for one hour. I would like to execute another command after a certain time since the main command has been started (at t_x). Something like this:

main starts   ------->  main ends
                  |
                  |
             at time t_x, second command is executed

At the moment I have something like this:

```
mpirun main_command & sleep 1m && second_command
```

and the problem is that after second command is executed, the main command is killed. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You can try something like: `(sleep 80 &); ls; sleep 5; ps`. Instead of "sleep", "ls" and "ps" you can use other commands.

Comment: It's unclear, to me at least, what the actual problem is.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: The output of the main command is defective (when the main command is finished); so I want to make a copy of its output before the main command is finished; I know at which time I should make the copy; but instead of doing it manually, I would like to atomise it. The problem with sleep is that it kills the main command before it is actually finished.

Comment: `sleep` kills something?

Comment: I am not sure; but after sleep and the second command are finished, the main command is killed...

Comment: @Azadeyazdan That's correlation, not causation. (Or at least, neither `sleep` nor the shell has anything to do with it. Maybe `second_command` does something that kills `main`).

Answer (score 0):

The first command is failing to lock the console, as another process is also using it. You will need to redirect the standard io pipelines, `0<&- mpirun main_command >/dev/null 2>/dev/null` If this still does not work, use `shell -c 'mpirun main_command' & sleep 1m;second_command` You can use `;` instead of `&&`, unless you need a failing exit code when someone interrupts the sleep.